# Solve: $(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos 2x+i\sin 2x)(\cos 5x+i\sin 5x)={i+1\over \sqrt 2 }$

Tags: complex-numbers

Can you please give me a hint for the following exercise:
$$(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos 2x+i\sin 2x)(\cos 5x+i\sin 5x)={i+1\over \sqrt 2 }$$

Thank you!

Comment: Use polar forms on both sides...

Comment: @Macavity But can you please explain me how can I transform the left side into a polar form?

Comment: You have the formula in the answers posted - use Euler's formula and you have $\cos kx + i \sin kx = e^{ikx}$.  Multiply three such terms for the LHS.  It is a more easy form to work with when you are multiplying such things..

Comment: So it's  the only and best possibility, is it?

Comment: Best probably yes, certainly not the only one - for e.g. you could multiply out the LHS to get a monster, simplify using trigonometry and equate real and imaginary parts.  Not something you want to do if you have other choices.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the top is given by $e^{ix}\cdot e^{2ix}\cdot e^{5ix} = e^{8ix} = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ and so $\cos(8x) = \sin(8x) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ implies $8x = \pi/4$ implies $x = \pi/32 + \pi\cdot n/4$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This was edited to consider less trivial solutions - if your goal is a complete solution set.

Comment: "implies 8x=π/4" No, one could also have 8x=9π/4 (and a few others as well).

Comment: $$8x=2n\pi+\frac\pi4$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Don't disagree. Edited to include other solutions as well.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe Euler's Formula? $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=e^{ix}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: convert to exponential form